# Why were these characters lying to the Resistance?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

**spoilers for The Last Jedi**

In this movie, Leia and Holdo have a plan to save the Resistance.  However, they keep it from Poe and the rest of the crew, pretending like they're going to abandon it.  Is there a reason they weren't sharing their plans with everyone else?  There wasn't a spy or anything, and it's not like Leia had any reason not to tell her army at this point if morale was so low.  Why all the secrecy?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the plan itself? Details are important, and I haven't seen The Last Jedi recently. Mark spoilers if you must but it's rather old.